# use the data from a join query inside lists (query builder) in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi im new to laravel and not much of a programmer so I have this code inside my controller that i wanted to get the result set that is based from database records then use it as a selection for a dropdown on my view here is my code inside my controller

```
$rcrdID    = DB::table('dbo_studentrecord')
                ->join('dbo_students','dbo_studentrecord.StudentID' ,'=' ,'dbo_students.StudentID')
                ->lists(DB::raw('CONCAT("ID ", dbo_studentrecord.StudentID, "  |  " ,dbo_students.FirstName, " ", dbo_students.LastName)'),'StudentRecordID');
```

im trying to make the dropdown look like for example:

ID | 1 | Billy | Joe | 12345

is there a better way to do this? thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make relation between the `Student` and `StudentRecord` model.

Student model (App\Student.php):

```
class Student extends Model {

    protected $table = 'students';

    public function StudentRecord() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\StudentRecord');
    }

}
```

StudentRecord model (App\StudentRecord.php):

```
class StudentRecord extends Model {

    protected $table = 'student_records';

    public function Student() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
    }

}
```

If you created the relation (one-to-one) you can use the below query in the Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Student;
use StudentRecord;

class StudentController extends Controller {
    public function getStudent($id) {
        return Student::find($id)->load('StudentRecord');
    }
}
```

[You can read about the load() function.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)